# Automatically getting a query instead of a result set in Symfony

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

In my schema, a user is related to their questions.

I want to display all questions asked by a user.

I also want this page to be paginated using `sfDoctrinePager` which requires a `Doctrine_Query` as a parameter.

I know I can call `$my_user->getQuestions()` to get all questions from my_user, but is there a way to get the query to get all these questions instead? Something like `$my_user->getQuestionsQuery()` for example.

Or do I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have to create a `Doctrine_Query` object manually:

```
$query = new Doctrine::getTable('Question')->createQuery('q')
     ->where('q.uid = ?', $my_user->getId());
```

And then pass it to pager:

```
$this->pager = new sfDoctrinePager('Question', $max_per_page);
$this->pager->setQuery($query);
$this->pager->setPage($cur_page);
$this->pager->init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations! You have ready to use *specialized queries*. These are just descendants of `Doctrine_Query` but with your own shortcut methods. There's article written by Nicolas Perriault called ["Optimize your Doctrine Workflow with Specialized Queries"](http://prendreuncafe.com/blog/post/Optimize-your-Doctrine-Workflow-with-Specialized-Queries), which describes this technique more verbosely.